# time data mm/dd/YYYY doesn't match format specified

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column with the following format:

Original format:

| mm/dd/YYYY |
| --- |
| 10/28/2021 |
| 10/28/2021 |

the output after:
`print(df['mm/dd/YYYY'])`

0        2021-10-28 00:00:00

1        2021-10-28 00:00:00

However when I am trying to convert to datetime I get the following error:

`pd.to_datetime(df['mm/dd/YYYY'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

> **time data mm/dd/YYYY doesn't match format specified**

Comment: The values in the `df` don't seem aligned, maybe there are some whitespace characters there? Try pd.to_datetime(df['mm/dd/YYYY'].str.strip(), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'). And please don't post pictures of the data. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for some guidelines

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I have edited now my question. I tried your solution but this does not help. There are not whitespace characters in the original file.

Comment: Just let `pandas` infer the format; use `pd.to_datetime(df['mm/dd/YYYY'])`.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong format. Try
`pd.to_datetime(df['mm/dd/YYYY'], format='%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: ValueError: time data '2021-10-28 00:00:00' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)

Comment: Hi, check `df.dtypes`, I think 'mm/dd/YYYY' column is already in datetime64 format. If you want to convert it in another format (string) use .dt.strftime() like `df['mm/dd/YYYY'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')`